# why we use training data in weka evaluation function?

Tags: java, classification, weka

I am using weka for classification. I am using different train and test dataset. I noticed that while evaluating on test dataset, we use training data in evaluation function. Does anyone know why we use training data? why not test data? I mean in following code, why we use trains in line 6 ? why not tests?

```
        1.  trainsource = new DataSource(train_file_path);
        2.  trains = trainsource.getDataSet();
        3.  trains.setClassIndex(0);

        4.  testsource = new DataSource(test_file_path);
        5.  tests = testsource.getDataSet();


        6.  evaluation= new Evaluation(**trains**);     
        7. model.buildClassifier(trains);
        8. evaluation.evaluateModel(model, tests);
```

Thanks! in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Because this is how the machines learn. They learn by using the 'training data' to train a classifier. WEKA takes the training file generally in 'arff format'.
Training data have lots of data under attributes. Example of training file:

```
@relation maitre

@attribute patrons {none, some, full}
@attribute waitEstation {0-10,10-30,30-60,>60}
@attribute reservation {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute bar {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute alternative {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute sit {yes, no}

@data
some,0-10,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,yes
full,30-60,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,no
some,0-10,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,yes
full,10-30,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,yes
full,>60,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,no
some,0-10,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,yes
none,0-10,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,no
some,0-10,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,yes
full,>60,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,no
full,10-30,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,yes
none,0-10,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,no
full,30-60,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,no
```

Now the classifiers can be of any type for example: naive bayes classifier, J48, SVM etc. When classifier is trained using training dataset, it creates a 'model' in terms of WEKA. Now you can validate your 'test set' using this created 'model'. So 'test data' is for validating the model.

Now if you train a classifier using above training dataset, you have now ability to predict the unknown classes. For example, if you want to predict the attribute 'sit'. You will need test data as following:

```
@relation maitretest

@attribute patrons {none, some, full}
@attribute waitEstation {0-10,10-30,30-60,>60}
@attribute reservation {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute bar {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute alternative {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute sit {yes, no}

@data
some,0-10,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,?
full,30-60,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,?
```

Notice the ? mark in place of attribute 'sit'. You can now predict the unknown classes. Hope this clears your doubts :)